# could we callback a function IIFE to reusable when we CRUD

Tags: javascript, json, oop, asynchronous, callback

is that possible to create reusable function in IIFE javascript ?? to CRUD by asynchronous data

const fs = require('fs');

```
(function writeFile() {


  fs.writeFile(filename, data, function(err) {
   // could we pass callback here ????
  });
})();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pass callback here"? `(function writeFile(fs, filename, fn) { fs.writeFile(filename, data, fn);
})(fs, "abc.ext", (result) => /* do stuff */ console.log(result))`?